# Best performant way for computing occurrences of values within nested structures, and updating the structures themselves

Tags: c#, performance, linq

What is the best performant way for calculating the occurrences of a value within a nested- structure, and then updating the structure itself?

The actual structures are more complex but for simplicity, imagine these are the structures:

```
public class MainStructure
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public List<SubStructure> subStructure { get; set; }
}

public class SubStructure
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string value { get; set; }
   public int occurrences { get; set; }
}
```

Additional Info: for each MainStructure, the SubStructure has 10 distinct **name**, and always at the same position. In other words, the 1st SubStructure.name will always be, for example, "Material". The second SubStructure.name will always be "Color", etc...

Now, in my code I have a `var allStructures = List<MainStructure>()` with 5000 entries in the list. Each of the MainStructures has 10 SubStructures. I'm trying to calculate how many times a value in the SubStructure occurs in all 5000 MainStructures, and update the occurrences property in SubStructure. For instance, if I have a MainStructure in which the value of the 1st SubStructure occurs 300 times, I'd be ideal to udpate all those 300 in the SubStructure.occurrences = 300.

I have thought about nested foreach(s) on both MainStructure and SubStructure with an 'if' to see if the occurrences property is already computed to skip it if that particular value has already been found, but I doubt this is the best performant way of achieving what I am trying to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some compelling reasons why `occurrences` needs to be in `SubStructure`?. It seems a little inefficient and separation of concerns problem. Could you not store the information in a dictionary somewhere, or use another approach?

Comment: Also note, if all substrctures of the same type are the same reference, then you would only need to update it once anyway, however that too seems fraught with issues

Comment: @TheGeneral the reason for having `occurrences` within SubStructure, is because there is further analysis to be done (e.g. rank) on the MainStructure itself. MainStructure has properties that are a computation of the values of `occurrences` for all its SubStructure(s). Does this make sense? If there is a different suggestion on achieving this same idea, I'd be happy to re-write it. Simplifying: MainStructure has a property that is the sum of all the occurrences of all its SubStructure(s), and then I can rank MainStructure(s).

Comment: Can we assume SubStructure has a FK like MainStructureId relation?

Comment: @Deniz at this time, it doesn't have a FK. This is all in memory. Handling everything via Linq queries...